# How to Executive Parameterized method in Ananymous window

Tags: apex

```java
public class helloWorld2 {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    public static void Method1(string firstname){
        firstname='John';
        //lastName='Carter';
        system.debug(firstname);
    }
    public void method2(string lastname){
        //firstName='john';
        lastName='carter';
        system.debug(lastname);
    }
}
```

Anonymous Window:

```java
Helloworld2 hw=new HelloWorld2();
hw.method2();
```

Error:
Line: 2, Column: 4
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void method2() from the type helloWorld2

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call **parameterized** method, you need to pass **parameters**.

```java
Helloworld2 hw=new HelloWorld2();
hw.method2('Smith');
```

Comment: public class helloWorld2 {
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    public static void Method1(string firstname,string lastname){
        
        system.debug('FirstName','lastName');
    }
    public void method2(string firstname,string lastname){
        
        system.debug('firstname','lastname');
    }
}


error:
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void debug(String, String) from the type System

can you please check this why cant we pass both

Comment: pass like this - method2('John', 'Smith');

Comment: Apex class is not saving its getting Error that Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void debug(String, String) from the type System

Comment: @Venkatesh System.debug takes exactly one parameter. You need two debug statements if you want to output two values.